# List all files in a Sharepoint online Document Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to list all the files from a Sharepoint Document List,

however I can't see to find a way to access the content list of the Document Library,

I was able to print the names of all the lists the Sharepoint contains, but not the  files a Document Library has,

Here is my example code:

```
private static void FList(ICredentials credentials)
{
    ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(" SHAREPOINT ADDRESS");
    ctx.Credentials = credentials; 

    List doclib = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Reporting Rosters"); 
    ctx.Load(ctx.Web.Lists);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (var list in ctx.Web.Lists)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
    }
```

The result is a list of Sharepoint List, I would appreciate if someone could guide me on how to expose the file names inside the sharepoint Document Library

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that actually will iterate through Files , subfolders and files inside those subfolders

```
var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);
private static void Flist3(ICredentials credentials)
    {

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("SHAREPOINT ADDRESS");
        clientContext.Credentials = credentials;  // passing credentials in case you need to work with Sharepoint Online
        using (clientContext)
        {
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Document Library Name");
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'><Query></Query></View>";
            Folder ff = list.RootFolder;
            FolderCollection fcol = list.RootFolder.Folders; // here you will save the folder info inside a Folder Collection list
            List<string> lstFile = new List<string>();
            FileCollection ficol = list.RootFolder.Files;   // here you will save the File names inside a file Collection list 
            // ------informational -------
            clientContext.Load(ff);
            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Files);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("Root : " + ff.Name + "\r\n");
            Console.WriteLine(" ItemCount : " + ff.ItemCount.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(" Folder Count : " + ff.Folders.Count.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(" File Count : " + ff.Files.Count.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(" URL : " + ff.ServerRelativeUrl);
            //---------------------------
            //---------Here you iterate through the files and not the folders that are in the root folder ------------
            foreach (ClientOM.File f in ficol)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Files Name:" + f.Name);
            }
            //-------- here you will iterate through the folders and the files inside the folders that reside in the root folder----
            foreach (Folder f in fcol)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Folder Name : " + f.Name);
                clientContext.Load(f.Files);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;
                foreach (ClientOM.File file in fileCol)
                {
                    lstFile.Add(file.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(" File Name : " + file.Name);

                }
```

}

Comment: Does this handle a multi-level folder hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over a ListItemCollection instead of ListCollection.

For that, you need to fetch all items in the list using CAML query and then iterate over that.

So, modify your code as below:

```
List doclib = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Reporting Rosters"); 
ctx.Load(doclib);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery camlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
ListItemCollection listItems = doclib.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var listItem in listItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(listItem["FileLeafRef"].ToString());  // gives the file name
    Console.WriteLine(listItem["FileRef"].ToString());  // gives the file's server relative URL
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this:

```
    ClientContext cxt = new ClientContext("SHAREPOINT ADDRESS");
    List doclib = cxt.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Reporting Rosters");

    cxt.Load(doclib);
    cxt.Load(doclib.RootFolder);
    cxt.Load(doclib.RootFolder.Folders);
    cxt.Load(doclib.RootFolder.Files);
    cxt.ExecuteQuery();
    FolderCollection fol = doclib.RootFolder.Folders;
    List<string> listFile = new List<string>();
    foreach(Folder f in fol)
    {
        if (f.Name == "filename")
        {
            cxt.Load(f.Files);
            cxt.ExecuteQuery();
            FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;
            foreach (File file in fileCol)
            {
                listFile.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```